# Get user azure object id from immutable id using ADF

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-data-factory

I have a data flow in ADF with a sql database sink containing a table with data for the following columns: UserImmutableId, Email.

I need to make a graph call to get the azure object id based on UserImmutableId. Is this possible in ADF data flow/pipeline?

Comment: can you provide more information abut whta you have tried?